# How to apply conditional statements on data read from CSV, during import?

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file that creates a bidimensional array with the cell values. No problem with this:

```
Column A | Column B |
10            10
5             10
```

But what I'd like to do is, by having a second file that includes rules, operate on the array data according to said rules.

Eg. The rule is: "for the column 1 if value is > 5 then make it 0"..
This rule is read from the csv file. So i can't directly program with static conditions...

What do you recommend for this case? Uploading csv data then a second file to manage the data according to the rules on it?
Using PHP? or what is best? I'm not sure.. because using eval() will require the client to know PHP programming...?

Comment: Really rules are plain-text?

Comment: This sounds like a perfect job for an Excel sheet? Or does it have to be online?

Comment: The language choice depend on which environment you are on... The script will have to be executed via a web interface (i.e.: a browser)?

Comment: The client will have to know *some* syntax. You need to strike a balance here: the more complex the syntax, the more the client will be able to do. The simpler the syntax, the less. A "rule" might be something simple like `{ column: 5,  rules: [ { 'min': 1000 } ] }` meaning to get the minimum of the CSV value and 1000 (so values above 1000 in column 5 will get truncated to 1000). Then you'll use another language - one in which you are proficient, and the clients need not be - to parse the rules and import the CSV to an "evaluated" CSV, or to another data structure (e.g. JSON).

Comment: I would do it on excel, but this is for an online task. Like upload and get the result.. I know guys this is not a cake. He wants even to allow to create new columns , move and delete.. I think i will use mysql, and let the user write the mysql query from the rule of the cvs, this also means the "the basic use  mysql query sintaxe must be known by the client." But this way it could import the columns and manipulate the data, and later export a new cvs table" Is this ok?